# Cannot convert anonymous type to int - compoiled linq to sql query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a compiled query but I just want it to return an int

```
        public Func<DataContext, DateTime, int>
    GetNextTourNo = CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db, DateTime day) => ((from b in db.GetTable<BookingType>()
                                                                              where b.RecordType == "H" && b.TourStartDateTime.Value.Date == day.Date
                                                                              orderby b.TourID descending
                                                                              select new { nextID = b.TourID +1 }).Single()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return `nextID` property from selected single anonymous object

```
select new { nextID = b.TourID +1 }).Single().nextID
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a bit more information on the anonymous type and the context of the compiled query?

Also if you are using the query directly in linq to Entity the date comparison will not work. Entity Functions need to be used for this. This could cause the invalid return.

Comment: There isn't meant to be an anonymous type. I just want the `new { nextID = b.TourID +1 }).Single()` to be a non anonymous int.

Comment: the error I get at the mo is Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<System.Data.Linq.DataContext,System.DateTime,AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Func<System.Data.Linq.DataContext,System.DateTime,int>'